# Body not wrapping content (not float or body,html 100% thing...)

Tags: html, css

Why the hell isnt the body/html or .main div wrapping my .container div's, when browsers width is between 767-960 px?! this cause you to be able to scroll horizontally. im so confused, this should work!

All code i have is this:

```
html, body { 
width: 100%;
}

.container {
  .clearfix;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {

.page-header
{
    height: 180px;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
}

}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code (HTML) here and create a fiddle.

Comment: Add this line in your head <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: nope, thanks but didnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by adding this to the media-query:

```
html, body {
   min-width: 960px; // <= width of the .container
 }
```

If anyone could explain this (why the .container isnt pushing body to be 960px) id be glad!